# How to count the total number of the row in mysql in this scenario?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on some forum like database

The structure is like that

```
post
---------
id

user
---------
id

user_like_post
---------------
id
post_id
user_id
```

The user_like_post is for a "like" function just similiar to facebook like. The problem is I would like to list out the post data, showing how many like for each post.

```
Result of post_list:

post_id   total_user_like
1         5
2         3
4         0
```

Like the above, how to query like that? Thanks for helping.

Comment: You've heard of [`COUNT()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/)?

Comment: ... and `GROUP BY` (also on that page)

Comment: ...ah yes, but of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to query your `user_like_post` table like so:

```
 select post_id,COUNT(*) AS total_user_like from user_post_like GROUP BY post_id
```

**EDIT:** and here is a SQLFiddle for you to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5137c/4